# How to Download File in PDF format when serverfile path format can be a (TXT, PDF, XLX) in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight

I have uploaded files on server. Now our requirement is that, when we select the file in any format, the selected files(txt,doc,xls,pdf) should be export in PDF format.
We are working in silverlight 4.
Any suggestion would be helpful for us.

Comment: There is nothing that will do this for you. Are the files some type of specific data or something where you could create reports from them and export to pdf? The only other thing I can think of is to buy adobe's pdf maker and there is a tool to convert files into PDF. Or, does this need to be on the fly with files users upload?

Comment: You aren't just trying to **download** in PDF format, you are looking for something that will **convert** any of those file types into a PDF.

Comment: Yes that's right. We are finding converter that will convert any file stream to PDF. But here we don't want to use any third party tool for converting pdf.If any Free converter available..... can suggest..